# update/reload collection view after deleting item from UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have used a collection view of photos for my app. 
I have easily deleted items from the collection view but it does not instantly remove the  items from collection view. if I go to another view controller and back to collection view controller then its become updated and removed the deleted items from collection view. I want the collection view to be updated instantly when delete operation occurs. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance. 
My swift code is given below:

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection = PHAssetCollection()
var photosAsset: PHFetchResult!
var assetThumbnailSize:CGSize!
var selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath]()

@IBAction func deleteButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if selectedIndexPath.count != 0{

                PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                    //Delete Photo
                    if let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection){
                        for a in self.selectedIndexPath{
                        request.removeAssets([self.photosAsset[a.item]])

                    }
                    }
                    }, completionHandler: nil)}


                self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is my viewWillAppear method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // Get size of the collectionView cell for thumbnail image
    if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        let cellSize = layout.itemSize
        self.assetThumbnailSize = CGSizeMake(cellSize.width, cellSize.height)
    }

    self.photosAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)


    if let photoCnt = self.photosAsset?.count{
        if(photoCnt == 0){
            self.noPhotosLabel.hidden = false
        }else{
            self.noPhotosLabel.hidden = true
        }
    }

    self.collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the reload method in your completion handler.

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                //Delete Photo
                if let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection){
                    for a in self.selectedIndexPath{
                    request.removeAssets([self.photosAsset[a.item]])

                }
                }
                }, completionHandler: { _ in  
  self.photosAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.collectionView.reloadData() }) 
  })
```

Comment: I have tried according to your advice but it does not work. I am facing same problem issue what I have explained in my question. I will be grateful if you give me further more advice. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. It might not be updating because one or both collection view data source methods are not dynamic. Can you add self.photosAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)  followed by self.collectionView.reloadData() in the completion handler and let me know if it has improved. I have updated my solution with this idea.

Comment: It works but it takes much time to delete and update the collection view about 10-15 sec. It shows warning like  "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release" and also show this  "  0   CoreFoundation 0x24d7b933 <redacted> + 150
 1   libobjc.A.dylib  0x24516e17 objc_exception_throw + 38
 2   CoreFoundation  0x24d7b861 <redacted> + 0
 3   Foundation  0x2566d3e7 <redacted> + 170 " type. Please give your further advice to solve this problem

Comment: Ok. It is saying that because collectionview.reloadData should be done on the main thread and not the background thread. Wrap the self.collectionView.reloadData() inside a dispatch queue like this DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.collectionView.reloadData()
} and let me know if that works.

Comment: it shows an error like "use of unresolved identifier ''DispatchQueue"

Comment: DispatchQueue is a Swift 3 method so it seems you are using Swift 2. Try use this instead,  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {    self.collectionView.reloadData()    })

Comment: Finally it is working very nicely . Thank you so much. I am really grateful to you.

Comment: You are very welcome. Please don't forget to make my solution the accepted answer and vote it up :)

Comment: when I am adding an image, it takes place last in the collection view but I want it will be shown in the 1st place in collection view. older images will take place last respectively.... for this can you give me any suggestion?